# Download file using Struts2 and ExtJS

Tags: extjs, struts2

I am new to ExtJS and Struts2. My requirement is to download a file (save file or render content in browser in a new tab) when user clicks on a link. I do not know the file type before I download (it might be a pdf, gif, excel, zip or something else)

I have constructed below **AJAX** request to call an action:

```
    Ext.onReady( function() {
      Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'action/download.do',
        params : {
          loc : path
        },
        method : 'POST',
        success: function(response, request) {
          return;
        }
      });
    });
```

**struts.xml** configuration:

```
    <action name="download" class="downloadAction" method="download" >
      <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
        <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
      </result>
    </action>
```

**Action** code:

```
    public String documentDownload() {
      String filePath = "/home/sasha/abc.pdf";
      try {
        fileInputStream =  new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
      }
      return SUCCESS;
    }
```

When I verified the response in Firebug it is "200 OK". The file content has been displayed under 'Response' tab in junk format.

Can someone please tell me how can I save the content as a file?

Comment: where do you want file type information? if you mean by content type you can pass them from your action like  `<param name="contentType">${content-Type}</param>` where you can set content type in action class

Comment: The file type can any thing. I may get that from same server or may request remote server. To get that simple I am reading a file ("/home/sasha/abc.pdf") from my local machine.

Comment: ok, than once you get the file you can easily find the file type and at same type set the type in your action class to pass it your config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get content type of the file calling `contentType = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getMimeType(file_name)`, and then use `contentType` in your struts.xml as parameter.

BTW there are more than one way to obtain mime type of the file see http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html